# Sqlite Query 'AND'

Tags: sqlite

I am stuck at a place where i am able to proceed with a sqlite SELECT query. My query is like this. I dont know if it tis correct or wrong. Please help me.

```
NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * FROM CLAIMS WHERE DATE = \"%@\" AND TIME = \"%@\"",splitdate,splittime];
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Nothing looks wrong to me. As long as the data you are passing in is correct. Check in the debugger what the string gets formatted as after that line executes, and see if that's correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL uses `'` for strings, so at the very least your query should look like:

```
SELECT * FROM CLAIMS WHERE DATE = '%@' AND TIME = '%@'
```

A further step would be to make those things parameters:

```
SELECT * FROM CLAIMS WHERE DATE = @date AND TIME = @time
```

And a further improvement is to use the SQL type `datetime` for the field so you'll only need one instead of 2:

```
SELECT * FROM CLAIMS WHERE DATE = @date
```

Comment: Thank u so much for the quick reply. But the value is from a Text field. so is this the correct way to do it. NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * FROM CLAIMS WHERE DATE = '%@' AND TIME = '%@'",splitdate,splittime];

Comment: The fact that it comes from a text field only makes it worse, but sure, that will work if it's only for yourself.

Comment: I tried with the above line of code but it didnt work. splitdate and splittime are string values.

Comment: IT didnot return data from the database.

Comment: It worked!!!. Thanks u so much. I had some white space in my string. It created the problem.

Comment: If i need to use DATE LIKE' ' what should i use?

Comment: Use date arithmetic/comparison instead (if those fields are `datetime` like they should be).